# How to Create an Array From JSON and Import the Values to Multiple Rows in a Google Sheet Using Google Apps Scripts

Tags: arrays, json, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to import data from the Google Search Console API to a Google Sheet. I was able to retrieve the data I need in a JSON format but cannot figure out how to transfer it to the sheet so it fills multiple rows.

I have the following function that is able to import the data, but only to one row:

```
 function dataFillTest(sheet, json, regex) {
  sheet.clear();
  sheet.appendRow(["Date", "Link", "Clicks", "Category"]);

  var data = new Array();

  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      data.push(json.rows[i].keys[0], json.rows[i].keys[1], json.rows[i].clicks);
  }
  Logger.log("Contents of data after for loop");
  Logger.log(data);
  
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  sheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 1, 1, 15).setValues([data]);

  var cell = sheet.getRange("D2:D");
  cell.setFormula('=REGEXEXTRACT(B2; "https://'+ regex+ '(\\w+)")');
}
```

This is what the sheet looks like when I run the code:

[image]

And this is what I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

This is how the JSON I have is structured if it is any help:

```
{responseAggregationType=byPage, rows=[{ctr=0.2625019822003836, keys=[2021-08-26, https://mondo.rs/Magazin/Zdravlje/a1522777/Letovanje-u-Crnoj-Gori-i-stomacni-problemi.html], clicks=120842, impressions=460347}, {ctr=0.18834311984734511, keys=[2021-09-13, https://mondo.rs/Magazin/Stil/a1528560/Hrana-za-jaci-imunitet-posle-50.html], clicks=102256, impressions=542924}, {ctr=0.23844989249500642, keys=[2021-09-07, https://mondo.rs/Magazin/Zdravlje/a1527110/Novi-organ-u-ljudskom-telu.html], clicks=93712, impressions=393005}, {ctr=0.27251045096802823, keys=[2021-09-10, https://mondo.rs/Sport/Tenis/a1528706/Novak-Djokovic-zamalo-diskvalifikovan-sa-US-opena.html], clicks=93349, impressions=342552}, {ctr=0.22042795846910482, keys=[2021-11-27, https://mondo.rs/Info/Drustvo/a1561695/Za-4-godine-ustedeo-7000-evra-na-grejanju.html], clicks=87129, impressions=395272}]}
```

Comment: I think most of us will want to see the JSON.  Because generally we will think that parsing it and reading the data out of a object will result in a much easier solution.  BTW the json that you have provided is not JSON.  Please provide valid JSON because we won't want to have to edit it to make it valid JSON.

Comment: I'm really new to all of this so I'm not quite sure what to add. The code I have to get the thing I called JSON goes like this: I define `var response_mondo = UrlFetchApp.fetch(apiURL_mondo, options);` and then do this `var json_mondo = JSON.parse(response_mondo.getContentText());` The `json_mondo` is what I send to the function.

Comment: I think I understand, do you mean this? `{
  "rows": [
    {
      "keys": [
        "2021-08-26",
        "https://mondo.rs/Magazin/Zdravlje/a1522777/Letovanje-u-Crnoj-Gori-i-stomacni-problemi.html"
      ],
      "clicks": 120842,
      "impressions": 460347,
      "ctr": 0.26250198220038362
    },...`

Comment: Yes that. [Edit] the complete json into your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why your data was written on a single row is because you are pushing a list of elements in your array `data`, then you made your `data` array into 2-d when writing it in your sheet [(Here is an example of what you are actually doing)](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp). Your array values should be in `array[row][column]` format when using `setValues()`, hence you should push an array to your `data` to make it a 2-d array.

### Sample Code:

```
var data = new Array();

  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      data.push([json.rows[i].keys[0], json.rows[i].keys[1], json.rows[i].clicks]); 
  }
  Logger.log("Contents of data after for loop");
  Logger.log(data);
  
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  sheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);
```

### Modifications:

- I enclosed the json data with `[]` then push it to the array `data`.
- Modified the `getRange()` based on the `data` array dimension

### Output:

[image]

Comment: It works perfectly, thanks a lot. On a side note, could you please explain the difference between a list and an array? If I understood correctly my problem was that I was pushing a list to data instead of an array, but I don't understand how they differ?

Comment: example your array = [1,2] then array.push(3,4) it will add the elements in the push parameter to the end of the array hence array = [1,2,3,4]. But when you push an array, array.push([5,6]) then your array will be array = [1,2,3,4,[5,6]]. What you did is to push all json data and created a 1-d array = [1,2,3,4,5 .... 15] then you convert them to 2d during setValue([array]).

Comment: But the format in writing values to your sheet should be array[row][column]. Hence you should create an array = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],....[13,14,15]]

Comment: I think I get it now. Thanks again for the help.